# How to get a Discord bot to send a message to a specfic channel when created?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot which on a react to a certain will create a channel...
That all works perfectly expect I want a nessage to be posted when the cahnnel is created which has a specfic beginning.

```
client.on('channelCreate', (channel, message) => {
    if(channel.name.startsWith('ticket-')){
        message.channel.send('test');
});
```

I'm not getting any errors, just nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `message` variable in the `channelCreate` event. The only thing you're receiving is a `channel` object, so you need to use `channel.send()`:

```js
client.on('channelCreate', (channel, message) => {
    if(channel.name.startsWith('ticket-')){
        channel.send('test');
});
```